# Best way to store some data Android

Tags: java, android, json, data-storage

i'm developing an Android app as a client of a cloud webservice. In the login screen, i download a lot of data as JSONs, like a contact list and a list of folders (only name and some feature, not the files included). After a deserialization of this JSONs, i'm storing the list of contacts and the list of folder in two static public list element on the .application file,  but in some phones (like galaxy S3 and Galaxy Note 2) when the application goes in background, they saves activities but not this list of data, so if the user come back from background after sometimes he found the app's contactlist empty or with a null pointer exception, because some phose erase this lists. Why? is that possible to save them in other ways? the data is complex, because a contact list object is complex and create a daabase is a lot of work. Another option can be the shared preferences, to store the serialized json of the contactlist, but it can be up to 2MB json.

Comment: Use sqlite with GreanDAO

Comment: read some tutorials on storing data. android supports sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation for data storage.

[Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Internal Storage will be the easiest solution. And would fit to requirements.

Comment: Thanks, i've read it a lot of times, but a sharedpreferences is too smal for it, a database noSQL isn't the simpliest thing to store complex data object

Comment: then try internal storage. it's a easy way.

Comment: this can be the simpliest solution i've read here. thanks, now i'll try!

Comment: i've a list of custom objects, and i can't call "getBytes()" to save it in a file.

Comment: can you convert it to string? Or try it with serialization.

Answer (score 1):

this can be a good solution for you : 
http://www.couchbase.com/communities/couchbase-lite

Answer (score 0):

I think that static variables are almost the first thing that are being garbage collected for memory purposes, so that's why you loose this data. 
In your onResume method check if your list is null, if it is start the download task again.

Comment: i have also included in my application a counter of started and paused activities to refresh data after lock-screen or background resume. This already works for all smartphones, except for S3 or Galaxy note 2 for example, where i can resume app for background but it doesn't refresh data. i try to add this control, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data which comes from cloud to database, then you must use transaction which will safely store all data first, then do other tasks.
Please, visit the following links to watch:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a very nice content-provider approach based on a small little project called Data Droid (http://www.datadroidlib.com/). The patter is very nice and reusable!